# How to make a double foreign key as a primary key in SQLModel resp. SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

Currently, I have two tables, `user` and `groups` and I want to associate them in table `group2user`, where I specify who has which rights to a `group` table.

Hence, I need two foreign keys in `group2user`, which should be able to do cascading delete (if we delete the `user` or `group` item).

For this, I wrote down the following code with SQLModel and SQLAlchemy

```py
import enum
from typing import Optional
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Relationship

class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    user_id: str = Field(primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_group: Optional["Group"] = Relationship(
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"uselist": False, "cascade": "save-update,merge,expunge,delete,delete-orphan"})

class Group(SQLModel, table=True):
    group_id: uuid.UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    user_id: Optional[str] = Field(sa_column=Column(String, ForeignKey("user.user_id", ondelete="CASCADE")))
    user_list: List["Group2User"] = Relationship(
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"cascade": "save-update,merge,expunge,delete,delete-orphan"},
       )

class GroupRights(enum.Enum):
    READ = "read"
    WRITE = "write"
    ADMIN = "admin"


class Group2User(SQLModel):
    user_id: str = Field(sa_column=Column(String, ForeignKey("user.user_id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False, primary_key=True))
    group_id: uuid.UUID = Field(sa_column=Column(UUID, ForeignKey("group.group_id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
                                                 primary_key=True, nullable=False))
    rights: GroupRights = Field(default="READ")
```

When I have a look at the tables (see below), I see the cascading delete for `group` via foreign key `user_id`.
However, the same does not apply for `user_id` and `group_id` in the table `group2user`, where it is a primary key, but not a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    user_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)


CREATE TABLE "group" (
    user_id VARCHAR,
    group_id UUID NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES "user" (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)


CREATE TABLE group2user (
    user_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    group_id UUID NOT NULL,
    rights grouprights NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id)
)
```

Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want a many to many relationship, you should use the `link_model` option on `Relationship` members, like the following.

   ```
   class Group2User(SQLModel, table=True):
       ...

   class User(SQLModel, table=True):
       ...
       groups: List['Group'] = Relationship(back_populates='users', link_model=Group2User)

   class Group(SQLModel, table=True):
       ...
       users: List[User] = Relationship(back_populates='groups', link_model=Group2User)
   ```

   See [the official tutorial](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/many-to-many/create-models-with-link/) for a detail.
2. If you want an association object relationship, you should define bidirectional `Relationship` members like the following.(I renamed `Group2User` to `Acl` for better readability. ACL means access control list.)

   ```
   class Acl(SQLModel, table=True):
       ...
       user: 'User' = Relationship(back_populates='acls')
       group: 'Group' = Relationship(back_populates='acls')

   class User(SQLModel, table=True):
       ...
       acls: List[Acl] = Relationship(back_populates='user')

   class Group(SQLModel, table=True):
       ...
       acls: List[Acl] = Relationship(back_populates='group')
   ```

   See [the official tutorial](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/many-to-many/link-with-extra-fields/) for a detail.
3. If you want cascade deletions on the DBMS level, you should do like this.(I changed the name and type of the primary key columns for better readability.)

   ```
   class Acl(SQLModel, table=True):
       user_id: int = Field(sa_column=
           Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
               primary_key=True))
       group_id: int = Field(sa_column=
           Column(Integer, ForeignKey('group.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
               primary_key=True))
       ...
       user: 'User' = Relationship(back_populates='acls')
       group: 'Group' = Relationship(back_populates='acls')

   class User(SQLModel, table=True):
       ...
       acls: List[Acl] = Relationship(back_populates='user',
           sa_relationship_kwargs = dict(cascade='all', passive_deletes=True))

   class Group(SQLModel, table=True):
       ...
       acls: List[Acl] = Relationship(back_populates='group',
           sa_relationship_kwargs = dict(cascade='all', passive_deletes=True))
   ```

   See [the SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#using-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-with-orm-relationships) for a detail.
4. As a side note, SQLModel project is in its pretty early stage at this time.(Even it has no API reference.) I don't recommend it if you are not ready to hack the source code.

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me. Yes, I saw that too, but I do need extra fields (https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/many-to-many/link-with-extra-fields/) and what is somewhat worrying me here, is that the cascading delete is not possible here anymore, which I do like quite a lot. Is there a way to make that possible here?

Comment: I added those cases to my answer.

Comment: Many thanks again, I tried out approach no. 3, sadly this is what I got for the Group2User table: `Indexes:
    "group2user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id, group_id)`, but not foreign key relationships.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] with a debugging detail(including your database driver). Your code in the question results in a name error.

Comment: My code did not work because I was having it in two classes like `class AclBase` which is `user_id` and `group_id` and then an extension `class Acl` with the relationships, but this has to be avoided. Many thanks for your help.